# Limit of series of Heaviside step functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, analysis

I couldn't find a better title, because it is a very specific limit that I want to show:
$$f_b(y)=\frac{2}{b}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\theta\left(y-\frac{k\pi}{b}\right) \rightarrow f(y)=\frac{2}{\pi}y,\;b\rightarrow\infty$$
I thought, that it would be helpful to use this definition of the Heaviside step function:
$$\theta=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\arctan(x/\epsilon)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$
Could it be some kind of Fourier series I have to work with?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $y \le 0$ the limes is zero and for $y > 0$ we get $f(z) = 2 y/\pi$. If $y > 0$ is fixed, we only have to consider the sum up to $n = \lceil b y/\pi \rceil$, because the other terms are zero. All summands up to $n-1$ are $1$. Note that $2/b \rightarrow 0$, thus the $n$-th summand is negligible, i.e.
$$\left|\frac{2}{b} \sum_{k=1}^n \Theta(y-k\pi/b)-\frac{2}{b} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \Theta(y-k\pi/b)\right| \le \frac{2}{b} \rightarrow 0.$$
Since $n/b \rightarrow y/\pi$ we get that
$$\frac{2}{b} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \Theta(y-k\pi/b) = \frac{2n}{b} \rightarrow \frac{2y}{\pi}.$$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. But I don't really understand how you did the first estimation where you get k(y/n-pi/b).

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my argumentation. I have corrected the answer and now the solution is also much simpler. :-)